# css, nested, first column indented, collapsible, table

Tags: html, css

Straight to the point, Can you make something like this in pure css

[image]

This is a table with four columns, where:

1. certain rows can be collapsed (~ `<details>`)
2. the first column only is indented
3. some columns have a dynamic width ( ~ `flex-grow` , `grid: 1fr` )
4. some control over the dynamic width

the underlying html structure would look something like

```
<entry>
   <A> example </A>
   <B> example </B>
   <C> example </C>
   <D> example </D>
   <sub-entries>
      ...
   </sub-entries>
</entry>
```

using just css grids and `<details>` I can get requirements 1,3 and 4, but not 2.

As a side node, for my specific case the html structure can be generated from code.

**EDIT**

Example of requirements 1,3,4: https://codepen.io/samcoutteauhybrid/pen/XWYpEZe

the point isn't to make this example work, rather a way to display some data in a table ( not necessarily `<table>` ). So the starting point would be some json-esc object which needs to be converted to html.

Comment: please also share an excerpt of the actual code. are you using a `<table>` element or is everything custom? when you say indented are you referring to increasing indents of sub entries(`details>details`)? or the `<summary>` elements?

Answer (score 0):

using custom CSS property for depth was the right approach. here's how you could implement it

in [your pen](https://codepen.io/samcoutteauhybrid/pen/XWYpEZe) make this change to your CSS

```css
.sub-entries {
  padding-left: calc(1em * var(--depth,1));
}
```

here `var()` resolves to `1` if `--depth` is not defined. you may want to use `0` instead. that way there is no default indentation for subentries

to set the indent, the markup has to be updated to

```html
<div class="sub-entries" style="--depth: 1">
  <div class="entry">
    <div class="name">indent me</div>
    <div class="type">don't indent me</div>
    <div class="sub-entries" style="--depth: 2">
      <div class="entry">
        <div class="name">indent me further</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PS: turns out cannot be done with `<table>` because only `<tr> <th> <td>` are valid children and the parser disposes everything else

Comment: this indents all columns not the just the first

Comment: ah. i had misunderstood your requirments. i'll update my answer after thinking of a solution

Comment: updated the answer! not possible to programmatically set the depth using CSS unfortunately. CSS does not provide "arguments" or variables that can be consumed. it is up to the web author to set them